# Android : Audio file from internal speaker

Tags: audio, internal, playback, speaker

I want to play a audio file from the internal speaker (that from which comes the voice during a call) it's possibile ?

Answer (score 1):

Use the [setSpeakerphoneOn](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html#setSpeakerphoneOn%28boolean%29) method of the AudioManager. This requires the MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS permission.

```
audioManager = (AudioManager)Context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
audioManager.setSpeakerphoneOn(false);
mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_VOICE_CALL);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer ! ;-)
I can play audio file during a call ?

Answer (score 0):

Question is a bit old. Anyhow, this method may help others:

```
    public void play(MediaPlayer player, String filePath){
    try {
        player.setDataSource(filePath);
        player.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_VOICE_CALL);
        player.prepare();
        player.start();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```